# High pitch squeal from MacBook battery running Arch Linux dangerous?

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, macbook-pro, noise

I recently installed Linux on my MacBook Pro (Retina 13" 2015/12,1) and it's now in a fully working state. The only worry I have is that, when on battery power (not when plugged in), there is a high pitch squeal sound coming from near the trackpad.

I have identified that this is likely from the battery area of the laptop and it only occurs when the battery current (via `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/current_now`) is low (around 500,000). The noise goes away when more current is being drawn (silent when `current_now` returns around 1,500,000).

Is the laptop okay to use and what is the likely cause of the whining sound?

Hopefully the battery doesn't decide to explode on me... so far the rest of the system runs as smooth as butter.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostriction

Comment: Does it make similar sounds when not running Arch, so in MacOS or another distro, with simlar current draw? [I think it's charging (& overcharging) that usually causes batteries to explode, but I wouldn't bet my lap on it]. If it makes the same sound with the default MacOS, might want to check into the warranty, usually only speakers & fans make noise, unless it's a regular hum that all MacBook pro's can make